# Permanent redirection from url mapping with parameters not working, grails

Tags: grails, urlmappings.groovy

I am trying to permanently redirect user from one url to another, and passing on the parameters.

Here is my url:

```
"/$lang/abc/$city/"
(redirect:[controller:'mycontroller', action:'xyz'], permanent:true)

"/$lang/xyz/$city/" (controller:'mycontroller', action:'xyz')
```

I want the user to be redirected from like:

```
/en/abc/dubai
```

to

```
/en/xyz/dubai
```

But it redirects to

```
/mycontroller/xyz
```

What could be possible solution? any help is appreciated.
 thanks

Comment: Well in your url mapping you said to redirect to your controller....Did you try :`"/$lang/abc/$city/"(redirect:"/$lang/xyz/$city/")`?

Comment: @YAT yes, its redirects to:  `/(*)/xyz/(*)/` .. dont know what its trying to do here..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way

In URLMappings.groovy define url mapping to some controller and action

```
/$lang/abc/$city/"(controller:"user", action:"redirectAgain")
```

and in user controller make and action and redirect uri again

```
def redirectAgain(){
    redirect uri:"/"+params.lang +"/xyz/" +params.city +"/" 
}
```